# Image difference in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a significant difference in a logo image i have when it is displayed in Chrome compared to Firefox (I did my testserver on Firefox and then live in Chrome)

Here are the 2 differences:
Firefox 
[image]

Chrome 
[image]

It should be appearing as it does in Firefox. I switched the logo and added in image characteristics to make it fit rather than editing the CSS file.

Here is the code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo09.png" width="250%" height="250%" alt="logo"></a>
```

Is there a quick fix to this? Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Tried using fixed `px` value on logo dimension? It looks like FF and Chrome calculate `%` value by different elements (FF on img, Chrome on parent).

Comment: I was trying to make the website as compatible for different resolutions as possible thats why i was trying to use the dimension as a % instead, is it not possible to do it this way?

Comment: I think you should use image in it's native size (best solution would be using image 2x bigger for hi-denisity screens but still in nominal (in that case half img size) - so it would look good at different screens).

Comment: I have just dropped it down to a suitable px size but it still appears to be displaying oddly, do i perhaps need a different CSS for Chrome?

Chrome:
https://gyazo.com/b8d6f31d431592c49ccb780304dff5a5
Firefox:
https://gyazo.com/44b7da7f20a2e844149bc634d1a2fcf6

Comment: You should put JSFiddle here, there is no code in your question (if you modified those inline % values) to show what's happening there.

Comment: Oh sorry yes i forgot to add the code, here you are :)

<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo09.png" width="255px" height="48px" alt="logo"></a>

Answer (score 1):

Use stylesheet, inline styles or *[Dimension attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dimension-attributes)* are a **nightmare to maintain**...

```
height: 123px; /*or any other fixed/dynamic value, unit*/
width: auto;   /*let the browser do the scaling */
```

would help (unless you're running into specificity issues)

Also it's goot to know that in **HTML5** `%` are not allowed on **attributes** `width=""` and `height=""`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

> ### `<img>` attributes
>
> **width**
>   The intrinsic width of the image in **HTML5 CSS pixels**, or HTML 4 in pixels or as a percentage.
>
> **height**
>   The intrinsic height of the image in **HTML5 CSS pixels**, or HTML 4 in pixels or as a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very dumb issue with Chromium. I'll assume this is what you're referring to specifically since I ran into a similar problem recently.
Chromium automatically applies

```css
    img {
        overflow: clip;
    }
```

All you have to do is overwrite it with `overflow: hidden;`.

I can't quite tell you why it breaks it, but here's my best theory:
I assume this breaks the `overflow-clip-margin: content-box;` property that's also set, that might be equivalent in some regards to the `box-sizing: content-box;`, atleast in behaviour. This is again quite a stretch to say, but it looks like the most plausible explanation to me, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the percentage width with a fixed pixel width. Firefox and Chrome register % measurements differently, due to the fact that the containers are laid out slightly differently. Also, add the measurements to a class and give then an `!Important` attribute. I believe Chrome has a css file it uses on all the sites visited in it, which gives some design layouts etc.

UPDATE:
After your comment, try looking in developer tools at the element to see if something is overwriting it. If there isn't, then I'm not sure what to suggest. Maybe go with a different design, such as a centered div with the elements inside, or use a navbar with this logo in, or a centralised logo without the bar. There are lots of options. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: I have just dropped it down to a suitable px size but it still appears to be displaying oddly, do i perhaps need a different CSS for Chrome?

Chrome:
https://gyazo.com/b8d6f31d431592c49ccb780304dff5a5
Firefox:
https://gyazo.com/44b7da7f20a2e844149bc634d1a2fcf6

Answer (score 0):

The issue you may be having can be related to your use of percentage. You set them to 250% but percent of what? It should be the parent element but what is the parent element set to? The parent of the image is the anchor element which has no width set and is not a block level element.

Try setting the parent element to some fixed width and see if the issue goes away or both browsers display the same.

For example, I set the enclosing anchor element to `display:block;` and set its width to 500px.