# Different outputs from Chrome and Firefox when I can't find any difference in styles in the console?

Tags: html, css, browser

Here is a [JSFiddle of the layout.](https://jsfiddle.net/06ec7f2m/1/)  I've looked at the styles of the .showcase element and of one of the .icon elements in both the Firefox and Chrome consoles and I can't see any differences.  Yet the gap between the two rows of small .icon boxes are different in either browser.  I'm only working at 320 x 480 resolution for the time being. I know the windows in the screenshot aren't exactly the same, but this is the case when they are both exactly 320 x 480px.

If anyone knows the cause I would appreciate the help!

```css
    /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */
    
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    b, u, i, center,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
    article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
    figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
    menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
    time, mark, audio, video {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
    }
    /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
    footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
     display: block;
    }
    body {
     line-height: 1;
    }
    ol, ul {
     list-style: none;
    }
    blockquote, q {
     quotes: none;
    }
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after {
     content: '';
     content: none;
    }
    table {
     border-collapse: collapse;
     border-spacing: 0;
    }
    
    /* End of CSS Reset*/
    
    body, html {
     height : 100%;
    }
    
    .heading-wrapper {
      height : 10%;
      text-align : center;
      font-size : 12px;
    }
    
    .non-heading-wrapper {
     display : flex;
       flex-flow : row nowrap;
       align-items : center;
      height : 90%;
       width : 100%;
    }
    
    .icon-select-outer {
       display : flex;
       flex-flow : row nowrap;
       height : 95%;
       width : 95%;
       margin : 0 17px 17px;
       background-color : yellow;
    }
    
    .icon-select-inner {
      display : flex;
     flex-flow : column nowrap;
      justify-content : space-between;
      margin : 0 17px 17px;
      height : calc(100% - 17px);
      width : 100%;
    }
    
    .select-text {
     text-align : center;
     height : 10%;
     font-size : 12px;
    }
    
    .icon-preview {
      height : 40%;
      width : 100%;
      background-color :blue;
    }
    
    .icon-showcase {
      display : flex;
      flex-flow : row wrap;
      justify-content : space-between;
      align-items : flex-start;
      height : auto;
      max-height : 200px;
      width : 100%;
    }
    
    .icon {
      margin : 2%;
      flex : 0 1 20%;
      display : block;
      min-width : 0;
      max-width : 25%;
      min-height : 0;
      height : auto;
      object-fit : contain;
    }
    
    .left-edge {
      margin-left : 0;
    }
    
    .right-edge {
      margin-right : 0;
    }
    
    .confirm-btn {
      height : 15%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Brad's Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen1-2.css">
  <!--<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/dee45a8958.js" > </script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="screen1.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="heading-wrapper">
    <h1>MAIN TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="non-heading-wrapper">
    <div class="icon-select-outer">
      <div class="icon-select-inner">
        <div class="select-text">
          <h2>SELECT YOUR ICON</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-preview"></div>
        <div class="icon-showcase">
          <img class="icon left-edge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon right-edge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon left-edge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
          <img class="icon right-edge" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
        </div>
        <button class="confirm-btn">CONFIRM</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Firefox screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbOfV.png)

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbDH8.png)

Comment: are you sure both dimension are exactly the same ?

Comment: The dimensions are different for the icon elements, but I'm not sure why that is the case.  The dimensions of each icon are 50.4 x 50.4px in FF, but in Chrome they are 50.4 x 63px.  I can't see any difference to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898706/image-difference-in-firefox-and-chrome), Firefox and Chrome calculate percentages differently? 
 The only solution seems to be to add a fixed px height, which I was hoping not to do.  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898706/image-difference-in-firefox-and-chrome)